# Socket communication between PHP server and ActionScript

Tags: php, sockets, actionscript-3

I am studying about socket communication and succeeded to connect between PHP server and PHP client. Now I want to do same thing with PHP server and ActionScript client.

http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php
I read this and could communicate between server and client on 2 Windows command prompts both in PHP.
So now I changed the client to ActionScript but it seems connecting to server but the string or number is not sent.

Does socket communication matter only address and port regardless of language? Or I cannot use two different languages to communicate?

For server, I used example 1 code in the URL above, changed address and port.
AS client is here, I wrote the minimum code, this would just send number when the file is run.:

```
import flash.net.Socket;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;

var s:Socket = new Socket;
s.connect("localhost",10000);
s.writeByte( 10 );
s.flush();
trace("sent");
```

And this is PHP server code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = 'localhost';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of  `Number(tin.text)`?. If it's larger than 255 it won't fit into one byte. Try doing `s.writeByte( 0x07) );` in `bsend` function... now does `tout.text` show a **7** when you add the line `trace ("tout.text is : " + String(s.readByte()) );` in the `socketread` function?

Comment: tin.text is what I type. So I tried to type numbers but it doesn't work. I tried to write the write Byte and flush outside MouseEvent too but still not working. Any idea why or way to figure out??

Comment: I changed the AS code even simpler, and put PHP server code as well. Hope if someone could help me out.

Comment: I will test the code later when I can. When you write a byte use hex format for numbers so **10** is actually **A** (0 to 9 is okay then its letters A to F for amounts of 10 up to 15) and is written `0x0A` so your code should be `s.writeByte( 0x0A );`

Comment: When I try with your Hex format then the server side says "PHP Warning:  socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
 in C:\finalproject\server1.php on line 38socket_read() failed: reason: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." Thank you!

Comment: That's strange.. I will test your shown later tonight. Bytes are always written in hex (not decimal amounts) so that's not the real issue... Until I test I cant be sure whats up with your AS3/PHP connect, but I put some testable code in Answer box cos too long for comments box.